# ¿Como hacer una captura de pantalla mediante código? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Necesito hacer una captura de pantalla fuera de mi app, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo. Simplemente realiza capturas de pantalla dentro de mi app.
Yo lo que necesito es hacer la captura de pantalla fuera de mi app. Ejemplo:
estoy en un juego y quiero hacer la captura de ese juego.
he probado modificando de todas las formas posibles esta parte del código:

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

pero nada.

```
 private void takeScreenshot() {




    try {

        File ruta_sd =  getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) ;



        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(), cambiotexto+".jpg");

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();


    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     cambio();
}
```

Agradecería cualquier aporte, Gracias.

Comment: cual es el proposito para capturar la imagen si ya se puede hacer nativamente desde android ? cual es el objetivo de tu app ? asi te podemos ayudar mejor

Comment: Una aplicación la cual tenga un botón flotante pequeño  y que al pulsarlo haga una captura. Y así no tener que presionar las teclas para hacerlo. Es muy molesto tener que presionar las para hacer una captura y más si es tablets

Comment: claro, ahi especificas mas el problema, cuando preguntes recuerda hacerlo de esa manera asi obtienes respuestas mas rapido :)

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta para futuras preguntas, gracias.